# Trigger Bitbucket Pipeline based on hashtag in commit message

Tags: node.js, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a pipeline that builds every time I push code to the repo. What I want to do is tigger the build based on a hashtag in the commit message. For example:

```
git add .
git commit -m "#slsdeploy"
git push
```

Any message (other than #slsdeploy) will just be the typical push to the repo. Below is my pipeline:

```
image: node:alpine

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - npm install -g serverless
            - serverless plugin install -n serverless-offline
            - serverless config credentials --provider aws --key ${AWS} --secret ${AWS}
            - serverless deploy
```

I've tried to research this and I have not found any information on how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It is way easier if you use proper git tags instead of magic words on your messages. Way way easier. The [skip-ci] thing is meant to prevent infinite self-committing pipeline cascades, but I doubt the other way around is truly a need but a convoluted git tag.